# How To Spiderfy Leaflet Markercluster When User Mouseover a Button

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I’m trying to spiderfy() markerclusters on a leaflet map when I mouseover a button.  Currently it works great when I mouseover the markercluster but not over a button.   Below is the script I’m using.

The markercluster spiderfy when I mouseover the markercluster using the below script:

```
markers.on('clustermouseover', function(a) {    
    a.layer.spiderfy();
});
```

It don’t spiderfy when I mouseover a button using the below script:

```
$('#container').on("mouseover", ".myBtn", function(a) {
    a.layer.spiderfy();
});
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer to my question after a little more research and the help from the follow post:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298623/spiderfy-all-leaflet-markerclusters-with-fewer-than-5-markers.  This provided the answer I needed for my situation.  I just wrapped the provided answer in my button click as followed and I got what I was look for.  I hope this answer helps someone needing to spiderfy a markerCluster with a button event.

```
$('#container').on("mouseover", ".myBtn", function(a) {
 map.eachLayer(function(layer){     //iterate over map rather than clusters
  if (layer.getChildCount){         // if layer is markerCluster
       if (layer._childCount == 5){
          layer.spiderfy();
          console.log(layer._childCount);  // log count of points within
          each cluster
       }
     }
  })
 });
```